# HTMLUnit Angular JS Seo not populating UI-VIEW from state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, htmlunit

I am using htmlUnit headless browsing for creating static content of my page automatically. 
But due to some reason my page is not getting the sub-child of ui-view inside it

Below is the code

```
try (final WebClient webclient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
        webclient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        webclient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
        webclient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webclient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webclient.getOptions().setTimeout(5000);
        webclient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webclient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);
                       webclient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webclient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(50000);
        webclient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        final HtmlPage page =   webclient.getPage("http://societyfocus.com/portal/#/login/signin");
        String finalXmlString = page.asXml();
        assertTrue(finalXmlString.contains("Sign in to your account"));
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

Request you to kindly suggest on the same.

This is base Junit test case. With reference URL. I am trying to generate auto snapshot creation and sending the same to google bot for SEO.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, Google executes javascript when crawling webpages. Angular websites are indexed without a problem (as far as I know). I don't know about Bing or Yahoo.

Comment: Google have stopped processing angular Javascript. I have tried the same using google webmaster fetch as google feature.

Comment: Is there any suggestions>??